# Filter in PySpark/Python RDD

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, rdd

I have a `list` like this:

```
["Dhoni 35 WC 785623", "Sachin 40 Batsman 4500", "Dravid 45 Batsman 50000", "Kumble 41 Bowler 456431", "Srinath 41 Bowler 65465"]
```

After applying filter I want like this:

```
["Dhoni WC", "Sachin Batsman", "Dravid Batsman", "Kumble Bowler", "Srinath Bowler"]
```

I tried out this way

m = sc.parallelize(["Dhoni 35 WC 785623","Sachin 40 Batsman 4500","Dravid 45 Batsman 50000","Kumble 41 Bowler 456431","Srinath 41 Bowler 65465"])

n = m.map(lambda k:k.split(' '))

o = n.map(lambda s:(s[0]))
o.collect()

['Dhoni', 'Sachin', 'Dravid', 'Kumble', 'Srinath']

q = n.map(lambda s:s[2])

q.collect()

['WC', 'Batsman', 'Batsman', 'Bowler', 'Bowler']

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided, all your list items are of same format, one way to achieve this is with `map`.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(["Dhoni 35 WC 785623","Sachin 40 Batsman 4500","Dravid 45 Batsman 50000","Kumble 41 Bowler 456431","Srinath 41 Bowler 65465"])

rdd.map(lambda x:(x.split(' ')[0]+' '+x.split(' ')[2])).collect()
```

Output:

```
['Dhoni WC', 'Sachin Batsman', 'Dravid Batsman', 'Kumble Bowler', 'Srinath Bowler']
```